# Do I need to create stream for generating a list in range?

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I am new in Java Stream API and trying to solve some exercises. In a problem, I need to return the odd numbers as a `List<Integer>` with the given range. First, I used a loop as shown below:

```
public static List<Integer> oddNumbers(int l, int r) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Then I thought that maybe it is better using stream in order to provide a cleaner solution. But it is not working when I tried with `filter` and `anyMatch`.

```
public static List<Integer> oddNumbers(int l, int r) {

    return IntStream.range(l,r)
        .filter(x -> x % 2 != 0)
        // .anyMatch(x -> x % 2 == 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

So:
**1.** How can I make it work using stream?

**2.** Should I prefer the second approach as it seems to be cleaner?

Comment: 1) For helping you with the stream approach ... show you code and tell us where you failed. 2) Asking for preferences is opinion-based and not appropriate for SO. 3) Please, do not ask several questions in one post.

Comment: Just a word to the stream approach: After getting used to the Java Stream API, I actually consider it as more readable. But, the main intent of the stream API is to separate the looping logic and the business logic that works on the elements. Using the stream API, you can focus more on the data.

Comment: I can see code using a for loop, but I do not see any stream approach, for which you told us that "it is not working when I tried with filter and anyMatch".

Comment: Harry ... my comment dealt with several things. The second question is still there, but still not appropriate. So simply delete it. Additionally, you now only showed the code using the stream API, but did not provide any proper problem description for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Like this:

```
public static List<Integer> oddNumbers(final int l, final int r) {
  return IntStream.range(l, r + 1).filter(i -> i % 2 != 0).boxed().toList();
}
```

2. It is a matter of taste, but one could argue that the intent is more clear using the stream API.

(`toList()` is new from Java 16, otherwise one have to use `collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Thanks a lot amigo, voted up. I also tried something and I am wondering what is the difference between `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));` and `.collect(Collectors.toList());` parts. Is there any difference (the former seems to create memory while the latter just return the result). Any idea?

Comment: `toCollection` allows you to specify which collection you want to use - `toList` makes no promises of which kind of List you get back. Both obviously has to use some memory to store the return value.